# How to get ttf/otf of a default font?

Tags: package-management, fonts, deb

I found a font that I would like to use on my website and it turns out that this is a default font that comes with Ubuntu. As it comes with Ubuntu, it is installed as a `.deb` package and after extensive search I found no other way to obtain this font than via this package.

Is there any way to get the ttf/otf from a package or a source where all the default ttf/otf of Ubuntu can be downloaded?

It's this font: https://fontinfo.opensuse.org/fonts/LaksamanRegular.html

I'm also very confused that - wherever I look for this font - I only find information about the Thai version although it obviously comes in a Latin version as well.

Comment: Use `dpkg -L <package_name>` to find the location in your filesystem where the font is located. There, you don't even need to download it.

Answer (score 1):

The font lives in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/tlwg/Laksaman*`. The font does indeed contain glyphs for the Basic Latin and Latin-1 blocks, and some few other glyphs in the Latin-Extended-A block.

Bonus:

`.deb` packages are `ar` archives; on Ubuntu, you can use the built-in Archive Manager to open them. On Windows, you can use 7-Zip.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I found it :-) Is it generally a good idea to use Ubuntu/Debian fonts in a web project? This font has a rather crazy license combination "GPL-2.0-only WITH Font-exception-2.0 AND LPPL-1.3c" and not even the package maintainers seem to cite it correctly... Can I use this in a commercial project (the font itself will not be altered or sold individually)?

Comment: I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice. But if it were me, I would forget about GPL and rely on [LLPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX_Project_Public_License) as a basis for using the font without restriction for any purpose. (Isn't dual licensing sweet?)